# How to set value to only one argument in the method using javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i defined the method like below that accepts four parameters with default values set and returns an object

```
const get_value = (first = 0, second = 0, third = 0, fourth = 0) => {
    return {
        first,
        second,
        third,
        fourth,
    }
}
```

And i want to call this method by sending value 3 to only fourth parameter...and rest of the values should be 0.

```
const output = get_value(3) //this assings first parameter to 3 but i want it for fourth parameter
```

How can i do it. could someone help me with this. thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another solution could be to put an object as function parameter, with some refactoring :

```js
const get_value = ({ first = 0, second = 0, third = 0, fourth = 0 }) => {
    return {
        first,
        second,
        third,
        fourth,
    }
}
```

Then you can call it that way :

```js
const output = get_value({ fourth: 3 });
```

Comment: This is the cleanest solution imo, since you don't have to worry about parameter order and you can easily pass more parameters to the function without needing to refactor it.

Comment: thanks this looks neat. so if dont want to pass any parameters to this then should i call it like this get_value({}) ?

Comment: yes, you can even set default parameter as `{}` : `const get_value = ({ first = 0, second = 0, third = 0, fourth = 0 } = {})`, then if you want to call it without any parameter you can just call `get_value()`

Answer (score 1):

You could call with `undefined` for not setted parameters.

```
const output = get_value(undefined, undefined, undefined, 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply pass 0 for other arguments:

`const output = get_value(0,0,0,3)`